# This is a Noteworthy Riddle

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

I am verifiable but uncommon.
I am always behind you.
I don't know what to say.
I am a lawmaker.
I am a cat.
I am an alien.
I am that with which I began.

**Who am I?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Are you ...

> ... **a trumpet**?

Because:

> ```
>       I am verifiable but uncommon.       T R U . . . .
>             I am always behind you.         R U M P . .
>           I don't know what to say.           U M . . .
>                    I am a lawmaker.             M P . .
>                         I am a cat.               P E T
>                      I am an alien.                 E T
>       I am that with which I began.                   T
> ```
>
> The "noteworthy" in the title could mean worthy of playing notes.

Comment: I love the formatting.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would show the structure of this nice puzzle well.

Comment: The answer is an alien after one who doesn't know what to say

Comment: I am an orange-faced president

Comment: @legrojan I am an alien orange-faced president.

Comment: @legrojan Truly a missed opportunity.